# Get assembly name of referenced method

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using the SemanticModel in Roslyn is there a way to get the assembly name of the referenced method?

```
var refMethod = string.Empty;
var refClass = string.Empty;
var refDocument = string.Empty;
if (location.Document.TryGetSemanticModel(out var referenceSemanticModel))
{
    var enclosingSymbol = referenceSemanticModel.GetEnclosingSymbol(location.Location.SourceSpan.Start);
if (!(enclosingSymbol is null))
{                                                        
refMethod = enclosingSymbol.Name;
refClass = enclosingSymbol.ContainingType.Name;
refDocument = Path.GetFileName(location.Location.SourceTree.FilePath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. I guess these two lines should work in your code:

```
var containingAssembly = enclosingSymbol.ContainingAssembly;
var containingAssemblyName = containingAssembly.Name;
```

ContainingAssembly has the assembly name, location, etc. information. You may put a break point and inspect it.

If it does not work, below is the code I use for the same purpose, which is working fine:

```
private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var invocationExpr = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
    var memberAccessExpr = invocationExpr.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
    var memberSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccessExpr).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
    var namespace= memberSymbol?.ContainingNamespace;
    var assemblyName = memberSymbol?.ContainingAssembly;
}
```